Attempt to delete a document on Mongodb Atlas times out and returns an error
I am using Postman to test deleting a document on Mongodb atlas in a NextJs 14.2.4 application using the api router. The problem is that my delete methods time out and the document is not deleted. This occurs with Employee.deleteOne({ _id: id }) and Employee.findByIdAndDelete(id). I have also tried the remove( ) method directly on the employee collection which also times out.
This is the route:
import { connectToMongoDB } from "@/app/lib/db";
import Employee from "@/models/employee";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export async function DELETE(request) {
    const id = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get("id");
    console.log('id: ', id);
    console.log('id type: ', typeof id);

    if (!id) {
        return NextResponse.json({ message: "Employee ID is required" }, { status: 400 });
    }

    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
        return NextResponse.json({ message: "Invalid employee ID" }, { status: 400 });
    }

    try {
        await connectToMongoDB();
        console.log("MongoDB connected successfully");

        // const deletedEmployee = await Employee.findByIdAndDelete(id);

       const deletedEmployee = await Employee.deleteOne({ _id: id });

        if (deletedEmployee) {
            return NextResponse.json({ message: "Employee deleted successfully" }, { status: 200 });
        } else {
            return NextResponse.json({ message: "Employee not found" }, { status: 404 });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error during deletion:", error);
        return NextResponse.json({ message: "An error occurred while deleting the employee" }, { status: 500 });
    }
}




This is my Employee Schema:
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const contactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  phone: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
});

const employeeAddressSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  street: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  city: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  state: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  zip: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
});

const geoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  lat: {
    type: Number,
    required: false,
  },
  lng: {
    type: Number,
    required: false,
  },
});

const assignmentAddressSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  street: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  city: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  state: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  zip: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
});

const EmployeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  isAdmin: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  contact: {
    type: contactSchema,
    default: null,
  },
  employeeAddress: {
    type: employeeAddressSchema,
    default: null,
  },
  locationName: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  locationId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
    default: null,
  },
  geo: {
    type: geoSchema,
    default: null,
  },

  assignmentAddress : {
    type: assignmentAddressSchema,
    default: null,
  },
},
{
  timestamps: true
}
);

// Define the model
const Employee = mongoose.models.Employee || mongoose.model('Employee', EmployeeSchema);

export default Employee;


This is the request url:
localhost:3000/api/employees?id=66972dc9f332a2f854b2cdc5
I have ensured that:

Mongodb connection is open
The object id param is valid
The object id passed in the url matches the _id of a document in my collection

Without fail, this is what is logged on the console:
id:  66972dc9f332a2f854b2cdc5
id type:  string
Connecting to MongoDB...
MongoDB connected successfully
MongoDB connected successfully
Error during deletion: MongooseError: Operation `employees.findOneAndDelete()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/Users/imarichildress/Documents/dev-projects/portfolio-new-2024/employee-mapping-app/vscode/employee-map-dashboard/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
 DELETE /api/employees?id=66972dc9f332a2f854b2cdc5 500 in 10869ms

This tells me that the client is communication with the server route. The failure seems to happening when I execute any of the delete methods.
I am sure the connection to my db is open because

My GET route to retrieve all documents works.
My POST route to create a new document works.

I have ensured that:

Mongodb connection is open
The object id param is valid
The object id passed in the url matches the _id of a document in my collection


Show the contents of app/lib/db.js. Need to see the connectToMongoDB function.

The node.js driver connects lazily, so the network connection may not actually happen until you try to use it.  Does connectToMongoDB() attempt to run a command like ping or hello to make sure the connection is ready to use?
